# Convert directory as string to json array node

Tags: java, json

Given this list as array of strings:

```
Cars/Truck/Regular
Cars/Truck/4x4/Lifted
Cars/Jeep/4x4
Cars/Convertable
```

How do I parse this into json like:

```
[{"name":"Cars","nodes":[{"name":"Truck","nodes":[{"name":"Regular","nodes":[]},{"name":"4x4","nodes":[{"name":"Lifted","nodes":[]}]}]},{"name":"Jeep","nodes":[{"name":"4x4","nodes":[]}]},{"name":"Convertable","nodes":[]}]}]
```

So far this all I have for recursive going through. Now will have to figure out the node class part.

```
String[] li = new String[4];
li[0] = "Cars/Truck/Regular";
li[1] = "Cars/Truck/4x4/Lifted";
li[2] = "Cars/Jeep/4x4";
li[3] = "Cars/Convertable";
doAll(li);
public void doAll(String[] files) {
    try {
        for (String file : files) {
            String[] f = file.split("/");
            if (f.length>1) {
                logger.info("directory:"+file);
                f = (String[]) ArrayUtils.removeElement(f, f[0]);
                String temp = "";
                for(String ff : f) temp=temp+"/"+ff;
                temp = temp.replaceFirst("/", "");
                doAll(new String[]{temp});
            } else if(f.length==1){
                logger.info("file:"+file);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

produces:

```
directory:Cars/Truck/Regular
directory:Truck/Regular
file:Regular
directory:Cars/Truck/4x4/Lifted
directory:Truck/4x4/Lifted
directory:4x4/Lifted
file:Lifted
directory:Cars/Jeep/4x4
directory:Jeep/4x4
file:4x4
directory:Cars/Convertable
file:Convertable
```

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: @FishStix added code

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to create a structure to holding those data first, then feed all data into the structure, serialize the result to json string at end. Pseudo code something like:

```
class Node {
  String name;
  List<Node> nodes;    // sub nodes

  /*
   Add new node under current node.
  */
  public void addNode(Node node) {...}
}
```

You start from the very first value say Car to create the structure, then try to recursively find left values say /Truck, /Truck/Regular in it's sub (or sub's sub) nodes. If found, do nothing, else you create a new sub node and add it to the node you last found.

Comment: confused on the recursive part. not sure how i should set that part up